# Ceating cross-sectional styled visualisation of multiple layers in map

Tags: shapefile, cartography, mapping, visualisation

Is it possible to create a map using multiple layers to visual them in a cross-sectional manner in QGIS, ArcGIS or R?

I have attached two examples to illustrate what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I understand that you are free with choosing the implementation technology, however I will suggest to stick to one software/tool/package/library...which one are you better in, e.g. QGIS, ArcGIS or R? Unfortunately, your question might be closed because it is opinion-based or too broad for this community.

Comment: Hello Taras, I am much skilled with using QGIS for mapping than the other software. It will be great to read you thoughts on how to perform this type of visualisation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nu_aur Thank you for the link, it really given me some insight on how to perform this type of visualisation.

It is possible to achieve this type of visualisation but it is a very crude approach. I am using QGIS 3 and its plugin called 'Qgis2threejs'. When using 'Qgis2threejs' in QGIS I highly recommend you set the 'Scene' settings to the following parameters:

Vertical exaggeration = 0.0

Background > Solid Colour = White

Now here is the crude part. Load a layer into QGIS and it should automatically appear in the viewer of the 'Qgis2threejs'. You can then tilt the layer to the desired angle and export it as a .png image and repeat the steps again with the other layers. You can import the images into a word document and crop. You can get the legends from the Print Composer by print screening and pasting it into word with the images.

[image]

It is a very crude approach but I hope this helps!

Comment: If it works, it works! Im sure there is probably a better way of doing it, or a commercial solution which would offer some assistance, but sometimes these are not worth the time/effort for the reward. glad to see a result though, well done.

Answer (score 4):

possibly one option is to create a 3d View in QGIS.
here is a link to using 3D views, for creating a DEM. but the same concepts could apply.
https://opengislab.com/blog/2018/3/20/3d-dem-visualization-in-qgis-30

Essentially create 3 different layers. Then, apply a different elevation to each 'layer' such that they 'stack' nicely. (the elevation doesn't even have to be real, just make it up).

The legend and labels are probably the only items which might not be supported. See how you go!

Comment: Thanks nr_aus for the suggestions on how to carry out this type of visualisation. I will have go at following the instructions in the shared link. Cheers!